# How to apply knockoutjs css binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'm not sure what is wrong with this binding statement.

```
css: { 'error': responseStatus < 0, 'success': responseStatus > 0 }
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/awoehler/zEn3t/

My server will respond JSON response containing either response.MESSAGE or response.ERROR and I want to apply a class based on which response I receive.

```
viewUserModel = {           
    serverResponse: ko.observable(),
    responseStatus: ko.observable( 0 ),  // -1, 0, or 1 
    displayServerResponse: ko.observable( false )
//....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When referring to observables in expression, they must be called as function to get their value. So changing this:

```
css: { 'error': responseStatus < 0, 'success': responseStatus > 0 }
```

to this:

```
css: { 'error': responseStatus() < 0, 'success': responseStatus() > 0 }
```

should make your code work.

Comment: Thanks that keeps throwing me off.